# iOS 9 status bar appears below black bar

Tags: autolayout, ios9, xcode7, size-classes

What is happening to my app in Xcode 7 / iOS 9?

[image]

The whole screen looks condensed, as if an iPhone 4S app is displaying on an iPhone 6. It looks normal in the iPhone 4S simulator.

I thought it was a problem with the auto layout constraints in the main storyboard, so I eventually deleted everything apart from the root view in the root view controller (blue screen), and there's still a problem with it.

[image]

I tried enabling size classes, thinking that this was the problem due to previously being disabled, but the result was the same.

[image]

Is anyone else getting this problem in their existing apps running in iOS 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the answers. They pointed me in the right direction, as I wasn't aware it was anything to do with the launch screen.

I found out I had no **LaunchScreen.storyboard** file. Digging around in the docs led me onto this:

> New projects are created with a launch screen storyboard file called
>   LaunchScreen.storyboard. Alternately, you can create a new launch
>   screen file using File > New, selecting the User Interface category,
>   and choosing a file type of Launch Screen.

[image]

It was weird that I had to do this, as I only started developing this app in iOS 8, and apparently this was a change in iOS 8. But with iOS 9 Apple are obviously getting more aggressive with deprecating incorrectly set up projects, and the consequences were that it was bug to my app.

The positive I guess, is that all of this forced me to at least create a launch image instead of having nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Target>General>Launch Image Source>use asset
it will create new asset named BrandAsset, place your launch images over here. Create LaunchScreen.storyboard if already not existing and select it to Target>General>Launch Screen File.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, but there was no asset created called BrandAsset. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction though.